# Adjusting Filter with Regex

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

Original Problem:
Need to count Multiple Criteria from one column in addition to a single piece of criteria from 2 other columns in one tab into a count on a separate tab of the same workbook in Google Sheets. I am using this to track progress in a project.

Suggested Solution (which worked! thanks @ErikTyler):

`=COUNTA(FILTER(CCSS, CCSS="Number & Operations in Base Ten", REGEXMATCH(Grade&"","K|1|2"), REGEXMATCH(GoalStatus,"Assigned to Writer|Goal Ready for Quality Review|Goal Quality Review Complete|Goal Ready for Copy Edit|Copy Edit Complete")))`

**Current Challenge:**

I tried to adjust the above REGEXMATCH formula by just changing it slightly and it did work successfully in 2 cells. But in another cell, I keep returning a count of 1, when I know it should be a count of 16. Any thoughts on what I am doing wrong?

In both of the below instances, I changed the Condition of Filter from CCSS to Phase, and changed the grade levels as well.

*Adjustment that worked correctly:*

`=COUNTA(FILTER(Phase, Phase="Phase 2", REGEXMATCH(Grade&"","6|7|8"), REGEXMATCH(GoalStatus,"Assigned to Writer|Goal Ready for Quality Review|Goal Quality Review Complete|Goal Ready for Copy Edit|Copy Edit Complete")))`

*Adjustment that failed:*

`=COUNTA(FILTER(Phase, Phase="Phase 2", REGEXMATCH(Grade&"","K|1|2"), REGEXMATCH(GoalStatus,"Assigned to Writer|Goal Ready for Quality Review|Goal Quality Review Complete|Goal Ready for Copy Edit|Copy Edit Complete")))`

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with _realistic-looking_ data, and showing your _hand-entered_ expected results there.

Comment: The first thing you'll want to do, since it seems that you may have instances of NO matches, is change `=COUNTA(FILTER` to `=COUNTA(IFERROR(FILTER` and then add one more `)` to the end of the formula. This will cause a return of 0 if there are no matches (or if there is some other error). As to why you're getting a number other than 16 when you expect 16, it is impossible to say unless I/we can see the sheet. Consider sharing a link to a copy with any sensitive data deleted.